# Can I duplicate a Twilio conversation?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-conversations

I have a specific use case in which I need to replace an SMS participant in a conversation (my conversations have one and only one SMS participant and several chat participants). The ideal solution for this use case is not to simply remove the SMS participant and add the new one, but to create a new conversation with the same messages and participants and change the SMS participant. Is there any way to "copy" a conversation using Twilio's conversations api?

Answer (score 1):

There is no functionality to copy a conversation. And creating a new conversation, followed by creating the messages again would send the messages to the participants. I think the answer here is no, you cannot copy a conversation.

You could perhaps create a new conversation with the new SMS participant and then do something in your application that knits two conversations together. I'm not sure why swapping out the SMS participant wouldn't work for you here.